# sending arguments from cmd to a c++ code

Tags: c++

I am new to c++.So please don't mind this question. I am using cmd from a windows10 machine to compile and run a c++ file. The code is successfully compiled without errors. While running the code, I am passing as a parameter- name of the input file that has to be opened by the c++ file But the connection is not being able to open successfully.

The code -

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    cout<<"The passed parameters\n";
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    cout<<argv[i]<<endl;
    int a;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(argv[1]);
    cout<<"Connection status\n";
    if(fin.is_open())
        cout<<"file opened\n";

    else
         cout<<"file not opened \n";

    fin>>a;

    cout<<a<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I save this file as h.cpp,after setting the proper current directory -
I compile and run it on cmd using the following commands

-> g++ -g h.cpp -o h -lm

-> h "\"r.txt\"

The output is 
The passed parameters
h
"r.txt"
Connection status
file not opened 
1627414140

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C, removing the tag.

Comment: `fin.open` doesn't want the file name in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the quotes.
Try this

```
h r.txt
```

else it will find the file `"r.txt"` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ h.cpp
./h r.txt
./h.exe r.txt # for windows
```

work's for me, output:

```
Connection status
file opened
0
```

Comment: 1. Might be worth explaining why

Comment: 2.  You don't need the .exe on Windows.  3.  You are very likely to need \ rather than /.